# How to convert a specific text string to today's date in Power BI

Tags: type-conversion, powerbi, business-intelligence, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with a column called that contains text.  Most of the values are years.  However, some have the value "present" to represent groups that are still currently active.  I want to convert those values to today's year, and convert the column type to date (specifically year type).  I want to avoid creating a new column if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below for the DAX language that worked.

= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Extracted Year2",null,DateTime.LocalNow() ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Disbanded"})